# Convert Android Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Android code, I need to convert an `Activity` to a `Fragment`. The issue is that I have to manage a view and I don't know how. Here a hypothesis of my `Fragment` code. But I don't know what is wrong.

I think there may be something wrong in `MyView.java`.

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyView myView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        myView = new MyView(this, size.x, size.y);

        setContentView(gameView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        ...........
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        ...........
    }
}
```

**MyView.java**

```
public GameView(MyActivity context, int screenX, int screenY) {
        super(context);
    }
```

**MyFragment.java**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);

        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        myView = new MyView(this, size.x, size.y);

        return myView;
    }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you've posted for MyView, the first argument to its constructor must be a `MyActivity` instance:

> ```
> public GameView(MyActivity context, int screenX, int screenY) { ... }
> ```

That's why passing `this` worked when you were using an Activity, but doesn't work now that you're using a Fragment. However, you can always get the fragment's activity by calling `getActivity()`. Since your view requires specifically a `MyActivity` instead of a generic `Activity` or `Context`, you'll have to cast the results of `getActivity()` to the correct type.

So, in your fragment, replace this:

> ```
> myView = new MyView(this, size.x, size.y);
> ```

with this:

```
MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
myView = new MyView(activity, size.x, size.y);
```